# Nest Protect battery_health property for wired device

Tags: nest-api

The [Nest API reference](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference) specifies a `battery_health` property for a Nest Protect (part of the `smoke_co_alarms` structure) which records whether the battery is ok or needs replacing soon.

But, a Nest Protect can also be wired to a 120V supply.

In this scenario, what will be the value of the `battery_health` property, or will this property simply be omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wired Nest Protect includes batteries for backup so it can function in the event of a power outage (see the "Tech Specs" section of the [information page](https://nest.com/smoke-co-alarm/inside-and-out/)). The `battery_health` property will indicate the health of the backup battery.